# "between" CSS/jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tree, jquery-selectors

## The problem

Given a jQuery selection of one element (`.context`), how can I select into it:

- the elements that are not child/grandchild of a specific class (e.g. `.paragraph`) [the class can have deeper nested levels of itself, like `.paragraph .paragraph`]
- the child/grandchild elements with a certain set of tags (e.g. `strong` | `i`)

## Notes

- `.context` can be descendant of another `.context` or another `.paragraph`.
- the elements I want to selects can be identified by `[data-hint^="I want"]` selector (obviously the data attribute is not present in the real scenario).
- I don't want just the direct children of `.context` but also the descendants (obviously filtering away the elements contained in `.context .paragraph`.

## The battle field

```js
$selection = $('.context').first();
$formatting_elements = $selection.find('strong, i')
                                 .not('.paragraph *');
```

```css
.paragraph {
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.paragraph .paragraph {
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
.paragraph .paragraph .paragraph {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.context {
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

[data-hint^="I want"] {
  background-color: violet;
}
.paragraph:before {
  content: '-paragraph-';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 200px;
}
.context:before {
  content: '-context-';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 200px;
  color: green;
}
.context .paragraph:before {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paragraph">
    <i>bar</i>
    <div class="paragraph">
        <strong>foo</strong>
        <i>bar</i>
        <div class="context" data-hint="Find elements relative to this element">
            <i data-hint="I want to get this">foo</i>
            <div class="paragraph">
                <i>bar</i>
                <div class="paragraph">
                    <strong>foo</strong>
                    <div class="paragraph">
                        <strong>foo</strong>
                        <i>bar</i>
                    </div>
                    <i>bar</i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <strong data-hint="I want to get this">foo</strong>
            <i data-hint="I want to get this">bar</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the above script but it doesn't seem to work.

## The goal

is being able to select and change *yellow* elements to be *violet*.

Comment: give it a specific `id` and call in jquery. this link may helpful to you
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 HTML included.

Comment: @Graham I am not getting what you are suggesting to do. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Edit

Sorry, misunderstood your question therefore re-writing the entire answer.

What you are trying to achieve here can be done using a custom filter function.

The theory is simple, you select all the elements that meet a specific criteria (including the one's that are children/grandchildren of some specific selector), then you filter your set out given the parent/grandparent criteria

```
var myElements = $('strong, i').filter(
    function() {
      return $(this).parents('.context').length < 1;
    });
```

See working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kzux3rfg/1/)

**UPDATE**

In light of your comment, I have made the following changes to the fiddle. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
var myElements = $('strong, i', '.context').filter(
function() {
  return $(this).parent('.context .paragraph').length < 1;
});
```

See updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kzux3rfg/2/)

Comment: This does not work, because `parents()` is a function that **returns the parents** of the selected elements (according to the optional selector); that is **not** for filtering the selected elements _:not_ having those parents.
In the markup that I added, (`$('.context').find('i, strong').parents(':not(.paragraph)')` returns just `.context`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. However the fiddle gets the elements **out** of `.context` (try to change the color of `myElements` to see what I mean). Maybe my question is not clear enough; I am looking to **select some tags** (`i`, `strong`) **descendants** (not just children) **of `.context`** but **not contained by `.context .paragraph`** (note that `.context` could be descendant of an outer `.paragraph`). The elements I want to get can be identified with ´[data-hint^="I want"]´ (just in the fiddle obviously).